# Macbook Pro 2016 13 inch - Display turns off whenever I physically adjust it

Tags: macbook-pro, display

Whenever I try to adjust the angle of my screen my display just turns off. I know the Macbook itself doesn't turn off because I can still hear sound and the keyboard is still lit up. But if I try to adjust the screen, the display just turns off and it's a gamble whether or not it's going to turn back on. I've tried closing it and reopening it but sometimes that doesn't work. I can turn it off and back on but again, the display may or may not turn back on depending on how it's feeling I guess.

Googling this hasn't been helpful, and Apple Diagnostics is reporting no problems. Any ideas?

EDIT: I've discovered that after closing the screen, I can adjust the screen to about 90 degrees until it turns off. Strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further Googling turns out this is a common issue with this model of Macbook. Apple will fix it for free. https://support.apple.com/13-inch-macbook-pro-display-backlight-service